# MariaDB / InnoDB: index corruption - why?

Tags: innodb, mariadb, database-indexes

I have a problem with index corruption on MariaDB / InnoDB. Today, i got

```
InnoDB: Error: Flagged corruption of <index> in <table> in CHECK TABLE; Wrong count
```

for 2 indices, and after DB crashes by trying to INSERT into one of that tables. I've fixed this by dropping and recreating index, but its the 2nd time now (last time 6 indices was affected), so i want to know: Why are my indices corrupt?

My only starting point now is, that both times i've updated MariaDB 1 or 2 hours earlier (via apt-get). But before i'll open an issue on MariaDB, i prefer to check for other possible reasons.

```
# mysql -V
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.19-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

EDIT: Happend again. This time not after an update, but after a long running query (DROP PRIMARY KEY on big table, takes 79sec). But how a long running query on table A can cause an index corruption on table B? Is my hard disk defect? Is it a MariaDB- / InnoDB-problem? Or ...?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MyISAM, switch to InnoDB.

This is another way to 'repair' the table:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

which will copy the table over and rebuild all the indexes.

`DROP PRIMARY KEY` is a 'bad' thing to do on InnoDB.  Can you elaborate on why you were doing it?

Comment: Im allready using InnoDB. Dropping PK was a one-time action, Im not doing this regular.

Comment: When changing the PK, it is best to do the `DROP` and `ADD` in a single `ALTER` -- else it has to do twice the work.